# Can import installed module but receive an import error when importing submodule

Tags: python, import, setuptools, python-module, python-packaging

The module which is installed using pip install --upgrade . from the project folder is importable however the submodules are not.

The module has the following structure:

```
mymodule
   |- setup.py
   |- mymodule
         |- __init__.py
         |- cli.py
         |- submodule
             |- __init__.py
             |- parta.py
```

In the setup.py file I've used setuptools with both the find_packages() syntax and the manual package specification. Both yield the same results:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mymodule',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={'mymodule': 'mymodule'},
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['mymodule=mymodule.cli:main']},
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

and

```
packages=['mymodule],
package_dir={'mymodule':'mymodule'},
```

When trying to import the module itself, the import works however the submodules are not usable:

```
from module
import module.submodule.parta

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'submodule'
```

Likewise

```
from mymodule.submodule import parta
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mymodule.submodule'
```

The `PYTHONPATH` variable does contain the directory where the module sits (`home/user/modules/mymodule/`):

```
printenv PYTHONPATH
/home/user/modules:
```

I've since tried adding the module itself (`home/user/modules/mymodule`) to `PYTHONPATH` and the outcome did not change.

The only time the submodule can be imported with no errors is when python is started from `/home/user/modules/mymodule`.

What am I missing? Shouldn't setuptools have found and copied all the needed files? I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: are you certain that "import module" is importing the module you think it is? After importing, do `print(module.__file__)`. Maybe you have a file in your path with the same name (eg: `module.py`).

Comment: Using that command where the submodule was not importable returned: `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mymodule/__init__.py`. When python is started from the module folder itself (and the submodule is importable), the command returns the following: `/home/user/modules/mymodule/mymodule/__init__.py`.